# How to increase vertical Nav Mesh detection for AI Actors? Using Default Query Extent?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, navmesh

For my swimming AI, I wish to use a Nav Mesh, so they may avoid obstacles and swim up and down - preferably.

I figured I should try to solve this with a nav mesh, since UE4 has kindly implemented it for us.

To avoid having the Enemy Fish stick to the "ground" of the map, I would have to increase the `Query Extent`, which is testable with a `Navigation Testing Actor` *(see images below)*.

So what I did:

- Add `Nav Mesh Bounds` volume;
- Add AI Actor with Character Movement Component;
- Increase `Default Query Extent` in Project Settings (Engine > Navigation System).
- No Profit?

Increasing the `Default Query Extent`, under `Agents`, increases it along the positive and negative *Z-Axis*, which is unfortunate, since I would like the AI to prioritize the bottom Nav Mesh surface.

---

I have attached two screenshots showcasing the "bad" behaviour, which I would like to circumvent.

The blue Bounding Box, showcases the *Extent*, which is scaled in both directions, vertically. Preferably, I would like to move it down, relative to the `Nav Agent`.

[image: The blue bounding box is the Extent]

To hit the point home, here is what happens when the enemy swims underneath some platform *(For simplicity, being the cube)*:

[image: Bad behaviour of Default Query Extent]

So my question to you good people is: how would I lower the Nav Mesh detection, without increasing the actor size, or something rather silly. Is there a clean way of having the "Enemy Fish" ignore the top platform as much as possible, without using a `Nav Modifier Volume` ?

Answer (score 0):

Unreal allows for several Nav meshes to exist in the same space. Look into the Project Settings, to try defining a different "swimming" AI nav for each fish.

Let's say you have a mackerel and a whale - both aquatic animals, both in the same space. However the mackerel can get into smaller spaces than the whale. If you use a single navmesh for both, either the mackerel will stick to open waters or the whale will clip into places it should never reach. The solution is to define a separate nav mesh for each animal.

This is where I would begin. Additionally, ask the question "Does the nav need to be walkable or can it be a 3D space for flying?" Walkable space is effectively a planar structure (visually), whereas a flying space is a volume.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, although I am afraid UE4 doesn't support volumetric nav meshes, or rather the Bounding Box itself is volumetric, but it calculates a plane for the AI to move on. So the only sane solution is to pretend the Fishes are anchored to that plane.

Comment: Thats right, NavMesh is not meant for flying/swimming.